# Rails Rspec No Route Error When Route Obviously Exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have been writing some rspec tests, and right now I want to verify a redirect after user creation. Many other tests work, including creating users.

However, the last of the following tests fail:

```
 describe "success" do
   before(:each) do
    @attr = { :username => "woweee123",
              :email => "email@mail.com", 
              :password => "password123",
              :password_confirmation => "password123"}
    end

    it "should create the user" do
          lambda do 
             post :create, :user => @attr
          end.should change(User, :count)
     end

     it "should redirect to a user show page after creation" do
         lambda do
              post :create, :user => @attr
         end.should redirect_to(user_path(assigns(:user)))
     end


   end
```

The failed test is: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"

But, when I create a user manually (on localhost) the redirect obviously works. Why is this failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Those interested the answer is that I had to change the test so that it looks like:

```
 it "should redirect to a user show page after creation" do
     post :create, :user => @attr
     response.should redirect_to(user_path(assigns(:user)))
 end
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if

```
assigns(@user).new_record?
```

is not true anymore after the post. It seems like it doesn't have an id in your test. Could some validation have failed?